# C++ separate definition and constructor of object

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Hello experts and pardon me for my rather stupid question. I am trying to use the 4heap priority queue of Professor Sanders, available at:

http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~sanders/programs/spq/heap4.h

Inside a function I can easily do:

```
Heap4<int, int> myHeap(myMax, -myMax, 10000);
```

The problem is, I want to separate definition of myHeap and initialization inside a struct, something like:

```
struct myStruct{
Heap4<int, int> myHeap;

void myInit(){
    myHeap=....
}

};
```

since I want to avoid pass myHeap by reference to other functions using it inside the same struct. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you probably should initialize `myHeap` in a constructor initialization list, this is how you can assign a value to it inside a function:

```
myHeap = Heap4<int, int>(myMax, -myMax, 10000);
```

**Edit** since it seems `Heap4` does not have a default constructor, then you *must* initialize it in the constructor initialization list:

```
struct myStruct
{
  Heap4<int, int> myHeap;
  myStruct() : myHeap(myMax, -myMax, 10000) {}
};
```

Comment: It does not compile. error: no matching function for call to ‘Heap4<int, int>::Heap4()’